# How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# type object?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc, list

I'm trying to post data from JS to MVC controller but the when looking at myobject the items 1-4 are all passed correctly, but the array shows with 3 null values?

can anyone explain where I am going wrong?

Model 1

```
 public class MyObject
    {
        public List<IDTT> list1 { get; set; }
        public int? item1 { get; set; }
        public int? item2 { get; set; }
        public int? item3 { get; set; }
        public int? item4 { get; set; }
    }
```

Model 2

```
public class IDTT
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "list1": ["1000", "2000", "3000"],
    "item1": "-1",
    "item2": "-1",
    "item3": "-1",
    "item4": "-1"
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MethodName(MyObject request)
{
```

Comment: Remove double quotes in your JSON if you want to treat them as `int` values

Comment: There are also tools for that like https://json2csharp.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list1` is a list of `IDTT`, not simple ints. Your json would be like this:

```
"list1": [ {"ID": 1000}, {"ID": 2000}, {"ID":3000}]
```

Comment: How can I convert from  ["1000", "2000", "3000"] which is currently stored in a var?

Comment: Typically you don't need to convert anything. What javascript library/framework are you using? You should just be able to assign your object to the data that is being sent by the *ajax* call.

Comment: Converted using 

    var result = selected.toString().split(',').map(num => ({ id: num }));